# How can I compute a surface integration from data?

Tags: python-3.x, surface, numerical-integration

Suppose I have a Nx3 array, where N is a giant number (the amount of points describing a surface) and 3 stands for the 3-dimensional space. This data describes a well-shaped good-looking surface with no discontinuities or singularities. How can I compute this surface area from the data?
(keep in mind that although the data provides a high-resolution surface, the spacing between consecutive points is not regular)

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible because points alone don't uniquely describe a surface. For example, in 2D:

[image]
[image]

You will need the surface cells.